# SSH problems with AWS EC2 - Permission Denied: Public Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-keys

From my keypair's directory:

`chmod 400 keypairname.pem
ssh -i keypairname.pem serveraddress`

Output:

`serveraddress: Permission denied (public key).`

When I check out the privileges on my .pem, I get:

`-r--------`

The path to my keypair is something like:

`/Users/myname/Code/AWS/projectname/.private/keypairname.pem`

"Code" is a symbolic link to a directory which is really two levels down from the desktop:

`~/Desktop/Stuff/Code/...etc`

From the above, is it clear to anyone why the EC2 instance is still rejecting my efforts to access it with ssh?  As far as I can tell, I've satisfied the requirement that my keypair file not be public.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a user. Otherwise it's trying to use your user which likely doesn't exist.

For example for a Amazon Linux AMI try:

```
ssh -i keypairname.pem ec2-user@serveraddress
```

The user varies based on which linux distro you are using. This [list](https://alestic.com/2014/01/ec2-ssh-username/) contains some common ones.